# SIP Register and SUBSCRIBE

Tags: sip

I wanted to understand nuances around REGISTER and SUBSCRIBE. In most you would expect UAC to register and then subscribe. Can UAC be Subscribed but not registered..? or can UAC be registered with more accounts than it is subscribed to.

E.g. REGISTER with 5 accounts and be SUBSCRIBE on 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no prescribed link between the two types of requests. They can share a common purpose such as updating and notifying about presence information but apart from those sort of cases they are largely independent in their purposes.

For example SUBSCRIBE requests are usually used to set up a subscription to send notifications about the state of a call transfer which is nothing at all to do with a REGISTER request.

And yes you could register on 5 accounts and subscribe for some sort of event on 3 accounts. You could also register on 5 accounts and subscribe for 3 different event packages on all 5 accounts so that you ended up with 15 subscriptions etc.

Answer (score 7):

A [REGISTER](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-10) message associates your `Contact` URI - where your user agent is - with your `From` URI - who you are.

A [SUBSCRIBE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3265) message indicates that you wish to receive notifications about some kind of event. [sipwiz gives an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13831517/10259) of being notified of the state of a call transfer (which actually uses [REFER](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3515) messages to perform transfer).

What kind of events? Pretty much anything you want. There are several different event packages defined for SIP, including call transfer (REFER requests) and [presence](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3856).

Answer (score 0):

If UA is using RFC 5627 "Obtaining and Using Globally Routable User Agent URIs (GRUUs) in the Session Initiation Protocol (SIP)", and SUBSCRIBE request has ;gr parameter in its Contact URI, then unregistering of the UA means that SIP proxy is not anymore able to route NOTIFY requests to the UA.